# QT function arguments

Tags: qt

Hello I am new in QT and I want to an make Log class.
I made **Log.cpp**, below code saves log messages in **Log.txt** file but problem is in function argument `QString msg`. I want user to type what message need to save by calling `logs.log_message("My log message").`

```
#include "log.h"


void Log::log_message(QString msg)
{
    QFile file("Log.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << msg \n";
}
```

And when i try to call that method in main function i have error:

```
Log logs;
logs.log_message('Database initialized');
```

**Issues :**

> C:\Users\ikac\Desktop\workspace\QT\Phonebook-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-*MSVC2010*_Qt_SDK__Debug..\Phonebook\main.cpp:15: error: C2015: too many characters in constant
>
> C:\Users\ikac\Desktop\workspace\QT\Phonebook-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-*MSVC2010*_Qt_SDK__Debug..\Phonebook\main.cpp:15: error: C2660: 'Log::log_message' : function does not take 1 arguments
>
> C:\Users\ikac\Desktop\workspace\QT\Phonebook-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-*MSVC2010*_Qt_SDK__Debug..\Phonebook\log.cpp:5:
>   error: C2511: 'void Log::log_message(QString)' : overloaded member
>   function not found in 'Log'
>
> c:\users\ikac\desktop\workspace\qt\phonebook\log.h:8: see declaration
>   of 'Log'
>
> C:\Users\ikac\Desktop\workspace\QT\Phonebook-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-*MSVC2010*_Qt_SDK__Debug..\Phonebook\log.cpp:10:
>   error: C2017: illegal escape sequence
>
> C:\Users\ikac\Desktop\workspace\QT\Phonebook-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-*MSVC2010*_Qt_SDK__Debug..\Phonebook\log.cpp:10:
>   error: C2001: newline in constant

**Compiler output:**

> 16:22:00: Running build steps for project Phonebook... 16:22:00:
>   Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step. 16:22:00: Starting:
>   "D:\QT\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"  main.cpp ..\Phonebook\main.cpp(15) :
>   error C2015: too many characters in constant ..\Phonebook\main.cpp(15)
>   : error C2660: 'Log::log_message' : function does not take 1 arguments
>   log.cpp ..\Phonebook\log.cpp(5) : error C2511: 'void
>   Log::log_message(QString)' : overloaded member function not found in
>   'Log'
>           c:\users\ikac\desktop\workspace\qt\phonebook\log.h(8) : see declaration of 'Log' ..\Phonebook\log.cpp(10) : error C2017: illegal
>   escape sequence ..\Phonebook\log.cpp(10) : error C2001: newline in
>   constant Generating Code...   cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi
>   -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"d:\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"d:\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"d:\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\include\QtSql" -I"d:\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\include" -I"d:\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\Phonebook" -I"." -I"d:\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\ikac\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.5108.31.jom
>     D:\QT\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug jom:
>   C:\Users\ikac\Desktop\workspace\QT\Phonebook-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-*MSVC2010*_Qt_SDK__Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 2
>
> jom 1.0.8 - empower your cores
>
> jom:
>   C:\Users\ikac\Desktop\workspace\QT\Phonebook-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-*MSVC2010*_Qt_SDK__Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2 16:22:05: The process "D:\QT\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
>   exited with code 2. Error while building project Phonebook (target:
>   Desktop) When executing build step 'Make'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `logs.log_message("Database initialized");`. Single quotes is used for characters in c++, not strings.

Comment: Cant beleve problem is be ""

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your String within quotes i.e. **" "**

use this:

`logs.log_message("Database initialized");`